# IRISO Status Query Required

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I require a query where I pass Internal Requisition No and gets the following Columns:

```
Item_Description, Requisition QTY Ordered, Reqisition qty Received, Intransit Qty, SO Ordered qty, SO Shipped qty, SO cancelled qty.
```

I have already written a query but its not working well....Plz help and Thanks in Advance

```
SELECT msi.segment1 item,
      msi.description,
      prla.quantity Req_Qty_Order,
      prla.quantity_received Req_qty_Received,  
     (SELECT quantity FROM mtl_supply
      WHERE req_header_id =
        (SELECT REQUISITION_HEADER_ID FROM po_requisition_headers_all
         WHERE segment1 = &&value1
         AND creation_date = (SELECT MAX (creation_date)
                              FROM po_requisition_headers_all
                              WHERE segment1 = &&value1))
         AND supply_type_code = 'SHIPMENT') Intransit_Qty, 
      prla.quantity_delivered,
      ool.ordered_quantity SO_Qty_Ordered,
      ool.shipped_quantity SO_Qty_Shipped,
      ool.cancelled_quantity SO_Qty_Cancelled
FROM po_requisition_headers_all prha,
     po_requisition_lines_all prla,
     mtl_system_items_b msi,
     oe_order_headers_all ooh,
     oe_order_lines_all ool,
     org_organization_definitions org
WHERE  prha.requisition_header_id = prla.requisition_header_id
   AND prha.type_lookup_code = 'INTERNAL'
   AND msi.inventory_item_id = prla.item_id
   AND prla.DESTINATION_ORGANIZATION_ID = msi.ORGANIZATION_ID
   AND ooh.header_id = ool.header_id
   AND org.ORGANIZATION_ID = ool.SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID
   AND ooh.source_document_id = prha.requisition_header_id
   AND prla.REQUISITION_LINE_ID = ool.source_document_line_id
   AND prha.authorization_status LIKE 'APPROVED'
   AND prha.segment1 = number_to_be_given;
```

Comment: You are double selecting `Intransit_Qty` and the first one is referenced from another select which is correct and the second one is not referenced from something.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that change...actually that was mis-typed :(